# How to Crop and Scale a Texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I have an input texture that is 852x640 and an output texture that is 612x612. I am passing the input through a shader and want the output to be scaled and cropped properly. I'm having trouble getting the `squareCoordinates`, `textureCoordinates` and `viewPorts` to work properly together.

I do not want to just crop, I want to scale it as well to get the most amount of the image as possible. If I were using Photoshop I'd do this in two steps (in OpenGL I'm trying to do this in one step):

1. Scale the image to 612x814
2. Crop off the excess 101px at each side

I'm using standard square vertices and texture vertices:

```
static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,
};

static const GLfloat squareTextureVertices[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f
}
```

I don't exactly know what the viewPort should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Viewport would be 612x612 pixels.

To scale and crop original quad the easiest way would be to set vertices to cover 612x612 rect (in your case we leave `squareVertices` unchanged), but set texture coordinates so left and right sides are cropped out:

```
static const GLfloat squareTextureVertices[] = {
    (852.0f-640.0f)/852.0f*0.5f, 0.0f,
    1.0f - (852.0f-640.0f)/852.0f*0.5f, 0.0f,
    (852.0f-640.0f)/852.0f*0.5f,  1.0f,
    1.0f - (852.0f-640.0f)/852.0f*0.5f,  1.0f
}
```